# Domain Forwarding gives 403 error for AWS and GoDaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, domain-forwarding

I have a client requirement for whitelabelling, for which I need to forward all requests at hello.example.com to data.value.com.

The url in the browser will show hello.example.com but the page loaded will be of data.value.com.

hello.example.com is hosted on GoDaddy and I have made the corresponding entries in GoDaddy

data.value.com is hosted on AWS with a Cloudfront Distribution.

Now, when I hit hello.example.com I get a 403 error from Cloudfront with the following error Message:

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
```

When I do ping or traceroute on hello.example.com, I am able to see that the ping happens on data.value.com.

What configuration changes do I need to make in order to re-direct my domain requests.

Comment: What is the DNS configuration that you put into GoDaddy?

Comment: Did you add the Custom URL into CloudFront? See: [Using custom URLs by adding alternate domain names (CNAMEs) - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)